# Remove characters from beginning and end or only end of line

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove some symbols from a string using a regular expression, for example:

`==` (that occur both at the beginning and at the end of a line),

`*` (at the beginning of a line ONLY).

```
def some_func():
    clean = re.sub(r'= {2,}', '', clean) #Removes 2 or more occurrences of = at the beg and at the end of a line.
    clean = re.sub(r'^\* {1,}', '', clean) #Removes 1 or more occurrences of * at the beginning of a line.
```

What's wrong with my code? It seems like expressions are wrong. How do I remove a character/symbol if it's at the beginning or at the end of the line (with one or more occurrences)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only want to remove characters from the beginning and the end, you could use the `string.strip()` method. This would give some code like this:

```
>>> s1 = '== foo bar =='
>>> s1.strip('=')
' foo bar '
>>> s2 = '* foo bar'
>>> s2.lstrip('*')
' foo bar'
```

The `strip` method removes the characters given in the argument from the beginning and the end of the string, `ltrip` removes them from only the beginning, and `rstrip` removes them only from the end.

If you really want to use a regular expression, they would look something like this:

```
clean = re.sub(r'(^={2,})|(={2,}$)', '', clean)
clean = re.sub(r'^\*+', '', clean)
```

But IMHO, using `strip`/`lstrip`/`rstrip` would be the most appropriate for what you want to do.

**Edit:** On Nick's suggestion, here is a solution that would do all this in one line:

```
clean = clean.lstrip('*').strip('= ')
```

(A common mistake is to think that these methods remove characters in the order they're given in the argument, in fact, the argument is just a sequence of characters to remove, whatever their order is, that's why the `.strip('= ')` would remove every '=' and ' ' from the beginning and the end, and not just the string '= '.)

Comment: +1 Regex seem like overkill for this. You may want to provide a 'complete' solution: `s.strip('=').lstrip('*').strip()`

Comment: @Gusto what do you get instead of what is expected? i just tested it again, and it works for me :(

Comment: Well, it doesn't remove neither == nor * signs.
I'm inspecting my code right now and I'm sure your code is correct... I'm still doing some wrong coding in my file

Comment: a slight typo at some places ltrip instead of lstrip. though +1 done.

Answer (score 3):

You have extra spaces in your regexs. Even a space counts as a character.

```
r'^(?:\*|==)|==$'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should pay attention to the spaces before "{" ... those are meaningful so the quantifier in your example applies to the space.

To remove "=" (two or more) only at begin or end also you need a different regexp... for example

```
clean = re.sub(r'^(==+)?(.*?)(==+)?$', r'\2', s)
```

If you don't put either "^" or "$" the expression can match anywhere (i.e. even in the middle of the string).

Answer (score 0):

And not substituting but keeping ? :

```
tu = ('======constellation==' , '==constant=====' ,
      '=flower===' , '===bingo=' ,
      '***seashore***' , '*winter*' ,
      '====***conditions=**' , '=***trees====***' , 
      '***=information***=' , '*=informative***==' )

import re
RE = '((===*)|\**)?(([^=]|=(?!=+\Z))+)'
pat = re.compile(RE)

for ch in tu:
    print ch,'  ',pat.match(ch).group(3)
```

Result:

```
======constellation==    constellation
==constant=====    constant
=flower===    =flower
===bingo=    bingo=
***seashore***    seashore***
*winter*    winter*
====***conditions=**    ***conditions=**
=***trees====***    =***trees====***
***=information***=    =information***=
*=informative***==    =informative***
```

Do you want in fact

====***conditions=** to give conditions=** ?

***====hundred====*** to give hundred====*** ?

for the beginning ?****

Comment: the result is exactly what i want, but i want to write it to a file (in utf-8 encoded) instead of printing. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following code will do the job:

```
tu = ('======constellation==' , '==constant=====' ,
      '=flower===' , '===bingo=' ,
      '***seashore***' , '*winter*' ,
      '====***conditions=**' , '=***trees====***' , 
      '***=information***=' , '*=informative***==' )

import re,codecs

with codecs.open('testu.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
    pat = re.compile('(?:==+|\*+)?(.*?)(?:==+)?\Z')
    xam = max(map(len,tu)) + 3
    res = '\n'.join(ch.ljust(xam) + pat.match(ch).group(1)
                    for ch in tu)
    f.write(res)
    print res
```

Where was my brain when I wrote the RE in my earlier post ??! O!O
Non greedy quantifier .*? before ==+\Z is the real solution.