# How do I remove characters from the beginning and end of a string, but not from the middle?

Tags: python, loops

I have been asked to write a function which returns a string with all the specified punctuations at the beginning and end of the each word removed **without affecting those which are within words** like ban,ana. How could I do this using loops?

```
    def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
        for element in punctuation:
            sentence = sentence.replace(element, "")
        return sentence

    print(beautify_sentence("?hello !mango! ...and., ban,ana.. yum?? apple!", "!?.,"))

    # correct answer = hello mango and ban,ana yum apple
    # my answer = hello mango and banana yum apple
```

Comment: Alright, have you done any debugging? Any idea where to start?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to coding so I have tried to use an if function to see if it starts with or ends with the punctuation but that didn't work, it just removed the first words punctuation but left the rest...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove characters from beginning and end or only end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113716/remove-characters-from-beginning-and-end-or-only-end-of-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you can use [`str.strip`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) on your individual words:

```
def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
    return ' '.join([x.strip(punctuation) for x in sentence.split()])
```

---

```
>>> beautify_sentence("?hello !mango! ...and., ban,ana.. yum?? apple!", "!?.,")
hello mango and ban,ana yum apple
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that python has strip, rstrip, and lstrip. lstrip and rstrip remove characters for the start and end of the line.

Using the similar code that you have.

```
sentance="?hello !mango! ...and., ban,ana.. yum?? apple!"
punctuations="!?.,"

def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
    words = []

    for word in sentance.split(' '):
        words.append(word.lstrip(punctuations).rstrip(punctuations))

    return " ".join(words)

print(beautify_sentence(sentance, punctuations))
```

But as already mentioned strip will removed front and back.

```
sentance="?hello !mango! ...and., ban,ana.. yum?? apple!"
punctuations="!?.,"

def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
    words = []

    for word in sentance.split(' '):
        words.append(word.strip(punctuations))

    return " ".join(words)

print(beautify_sentence(sentance, punctuations))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a learning task. So, I am sharing another approach to solve this problem.

**Alternative Approach**

We can iterate the sentence and remove any listed punctuation which are not middle of any word.

```
def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
    beautiful_sentence = ""
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        if sentence[i] in punctuation:
            # remove punctuation at start and end of a sentence
            if i == 0 or i == len(sentence)-1:
                continue
            # remove punctuation which are not in middle of a word
            if not sentence[i-1].isalpha() or not sentence[i+1].isalpha():
                continue
        beautiful_sentence += sentence[i]
    return beautiful_sentence


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_sentence = "?hello !mango! ...and., ban,ana.. yum?? apple!"
    test_punctuations = "!?.,"
    expected_sentence = "hello mango and ban,ana yum apple"
    sentence = beautify_sentence(test_sentence, test_punctuations)
    assert sentence == expected_sentence, (expected_sentence, sentence)
```

This is not tested for all test cases though. You may need to modify it to meet all criterias.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit longer, but I hope you can easily understand the algorithm from this step by step approach.

```
def beautify(sentence, punctuation):
    sen = sentence
    punc = punctuation

    words = sen.split(" ")  # splits into a list of words

    ret = []  # return the processed words

    for word in words:  # process each word one by one
        noPuncInTheStart = False
        noPuncInTheEnd = False

        # don't really mind this. See the break statements! 
        while (True):

            # Check the length of the word to prevent error
            # And if there is any punctuation in the beginning
            if (len(word) > 0 and not noPuncInTheStart):
                if (word[0] in punc):  # if the word started by punc
                    word = word[1:]  # remove the first character
                else:  # there is no any punctuation anymore
                    noPuncInTheStart = True
            else:
                # the word is no longger exists :)
                # in case the word is all punctuation, no letters, etc
                break

            if (len(word) > 0 and not noPuncInTheEnd):
                if (word[-1] in punc):  # check if the end is a punc
                    word = word[:-1]  # remove the end of the character
                else: 
                    noPuncInTheEnd = True
            else:
                break

            if (noPuncInTheStart and noPuncInTheEnd):
                # there's no longger punc, neither in the beginning
                # nor the end
                break  

        ret.append(word)  # add the processed word to the `ret` list
    ret = " ".join(ret)  # join the `ret` list into sentence
    return ret
```